# Collision between two character controller

Tags: collision-detection, unity-game-engine

Hello everyone I am new in unity. I create two character on my project. They can move easily. But the problem is I cannot make collision between them. Please help me. Give me some code.....

Comment: Questions with "Give me some code" are unlikely to be answered.  I suggest reading through some Unity tutorials to learn how to handle collision detection.

Answer (score 6):

First, do you want to 'make' ridigbodies collide or detect the collision?

Assuming the latter because that is mostly the objective, collision detection is a very wide topic, and it is difficult to give an exact answer without knowing what exactly is the problem you are facing, and since you are learning, i am giving some links which should be helpful in understanding and implementing collision detection in Unity3d.

What you need to study in order to do collision detection is Raycasting. Second, about your specific problem (colliding character controllers) no code can be give since you didn't give any details about your game environment and what have you created, but [this](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Components/comp-DynamicsGroup.html) should be helpful (study the heading Character Controllers), but do study the basic of collisions and collision detection in detail.

and the links:

- [Unity3d documentation:
  Physics](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Manual/Physics.html)
- [A question about learning collision detection on Unity3d
  Forums](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/26847-collision-detection-tutorial)
- [Apparently a good
  tutorial](http://www.unity3dstudent.com/2010/07/beginner-b01-basic-collision-detection/)
- [Raycast script
  reference](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html)

Hope this helps.

In future do mention your specific problem, and what you have done so far, or if you want to start learning, do mention clearly what you want to learn.